Set foreach microbatch data count in structured streaming
We are utilizing a structured streaming flow in Databricks, employing the foreach functionality for transformations and actions, and ultimately writing the data into a Delta table. Our data sources are Eventhub, Delta table, or Azure Cosmos change feed. When significant data changes occur in the source (Delta table, Azure SQL, or Cosmos), we need to split the data into smaller chunks during the streaming process while reading change data from the source. Specifically, we need to set a micro-batch count limit within the foreach functionality in the structured streaming flow.

I think the question is a bit too generic. Each source has different way of limiting batch size

I required for delta file based read stream, here I want to set the processing foreach microbatch limit count.

For Delta tables, set options maxFilesPerTrigger and/or maxBytesPerTrigger:
spark.readStream
    .format("delta")
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", "100")
    .option("maxBytesPerTrigger", "5g")

Note that if you have one big file it will not be split into multiple batches

Worth to add maxFilesPerTrigger is only useful when input files are more or less the same size. If these greatly vary (could be 100K or 10G), then this property provides no value. Having that, maxBytesPerTrigger is the best choice literally in every scenario even if it cannot split files (maxFilesPerTrigger cannot split either!).
